# How to put the verification code sent to the phone from the console to a pyqt5 widget?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a library in my code that I import it to login to Robinhood trading system.

When the user login in their account, RobinHood server will send an int code to input. This would show as an input in the console. However, I managed to created a pyqt5 input dialog box to ask the user to input the code in it. Then I tried so many ways to forward that code to the input() box even by printing it and hitting 'Enter' after the user hits the button in the message box but it is still not taking the input. I would love to know how I fix this issue and how to find a way to put values in the input() box using pyqt5

These are two functions in a class I have:
The dialog box:

```
def getCode(self):
    keyboard=Controller()
    self.logging, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Get Robinhood code', 'Robinhood Code:')

    if okPressed:
        print(self.logging)
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
```

The login code:

```
def connecting(self):
    import robin_stocks as robin
    self.robin=robin.login(self.robinuser.text(), self.robinpass.text())
```

and the calling code in my "main":

```
connecting()
getCode()
```

The whole code can be like this example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Controller
import robin_stocks as robin

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 input dialogs - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 500
        self.top = 500
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.connecting()


    def getCode(self):
        keyboard=Controller()
        i, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Get Robinhood code', 'Robinhood Code:')

        if okPressed:
            print(i)
            keyboard.press(Key.enter)

    def connecting(self):

        robin.login('self.robinuser.text()', 'self.robinpass.text()')
        self.getCode()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: So far I do not understand why it is necessary to use the console and less emulate the enter.

Comment: I am not an expert in programming, you have another way? please teach me, I am stuck with this for more than a month

Comment: The time you are stuck is irrelevant (they are just noise). On the other hand it is not clear to me where you want to use "Robinhood Code"

Comment: I have added a picture, in general, it is just a verification code I need to send it back to the server for robin_stock using message box, so get a permission to login.

Comment: Robinhood is a trading platform,  I use it to automate my trades

Comment: To provide a possible solution I need to test it for what I need a username, password and Robinhood Code, if you provide them I could help you.

Comment: I cannot make it public to everyone is there another way i can give to you only?

Comment: I emailed you the username and the password, let ne know if you have not received them, thank you again for the assistance.

Comment: Can you also send me the verification code?

Comment: I did send them

Comment: I keep sending them

Comment: okay, don't send me any more codes, I already understood how it works.

Comment: A question: do you get the code from trying to login or can you get the code before trying to login? Or rather, how do you get the code?

Comment: before you login, when you login you do not need the code anymore

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. Can you get the code before logging in? That is, can you get a code that you can use after T seconds?

Comment: Or every time you run *robin.login(X, Y)* does the system send you an SMS?

Comment: After I get the code, I can use it within 5 Min, Like your example, you are sending the request to me and I reply back this can take about a minute (I think) and you still can login

Comment: Yes, every time you run robin.login(X,Y) I get a login however, once you logged in I do not get a message anymore

Comment: So, let's say you run it now, you are in, now you run robin.login(X,Y), I do not get the code again. you are in for 24 hours or 86400sec

Comment: try with my solution

Comment: some feedback??

Answer (score 0):

I find it very difficult to try to write on the console since doing so depends on the OS, instead a possible solution is to modify the login method so that instead of using as input to input() use QInputDialog.

Simply copy the login method, add the necessary imports by changing some parts, and replacing input() with QInputDialog.

```py
import os
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

import robin_stocks as robin

import robin_stocks.urls as urls
import robin_stocks.helper as helper
import robin_stocks.authentication as authentication


def login(
    username,
    password,
    expiresIn=86400,
    scope="internal",
    by_sms=True,
    store_session=True,
):
    """This function will effectivly log the user into robinhood by getting an
    authentication token and saving it to the session header. By default, it will store the authentication
    token in a pickle file and load that value on subsequent logins.
    :param username: The username for your robinhood account. Usually your email.
    :type username: str
    :param password: The password for your robinhood account.
    :type password: str
    :param expiresIn: The time until your login session expires. This is in seconds.
    :type expiresIn: Optional[int]
    :param scope: Specifies the scope of the authentication.
    :type scope: Optional[str]
    :param by_sms: Specifies whether to send an email(False) or an sms(True)
    :type by_sms: Optional[boolean]
    :param store_session: Specifies whether to save the log in authorization for future log ins.
    :type store_session: Optional[boolean]
    :returns:  A dictionary with log in information. The 'access_token' keyword contains the access token, and the 'detail' keyword \
    contains information on whether the access token was generated or loaded from pickle file.
    """
    device_token = authentication.generate_device_token()
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    pickle_path = os.path.join(dir_path, "data.pickle")
    # Challenge type is used if not logging in with two-factor authentication.
    if by_sms:
        challenge_type = "sms"
    else:
        challenge_type = "email"

    url = urls.login_url()
    payload = {
        "client_id": "c82SH0WZOsabOXGP2sxqcj34FxkvfnWRZBKlBjFS",
        "expires_in": expiresIn,
        "grant_type": "password",
        "password": password,
        "scope": scope,
        "username": username,
        "challenge_type": challenge_type,
        "device_token": device_token,
    }
    # If authentication has been stored in pickle file then load it. Stops login server from being pinged so much.
    if os.path.isfile(pickle_path):
        # If store_session has been set to false then delete the pickle file, otherwise try to load it.
        # Loading pickle file will fail if the acess_token has expired.
        if store_session:
            try:
                with open(pickle_path, "rb") as f:
                    pickle_data = pickle.load(f)
                    access_token = pickle_data["access_token"]
                    token_type = pickle_data["token_type"]
                    refresh_token = pickle_data["refresh_token"]
                    # Set device_token to be the original device token when first logged in.
                    pickle_device_token = pickle_data["device_token"]
                    payload["device_token"] = pickle_device_token
                    # Set login status to True in order to try and get account info.
                    helper.set_login_state(True)
                    helper.update_session(
                        "Authorization", "{0} {1}".format(token_type, access_token)
                    )
                    # Try to load account profile to check that authorization token is still valid.
                    res = helper.request_get(
                        urls.portfolio_profile(), "regular", payload, jsonify_data=False
                    )
                    # Raises exception is response code is not 200.
                    res.raise_for_status()
                    return {
                        "access_token": access_token,
                        "token_type": token_type,
                        "expires_in": expiresIn,
                        "scope": scope,
                        "detail": "logged in using authentication in data.pickle",
                        "backup_code": None,
                        "refresh_token": refresh_token,
                    }
            except:
                print(
                    "ERROR: There was an issue loading pickle file. Authentication may be expired - logging in normally."
                )
                helper.set_login_state(False)
                helper.update_session("Authorization", None)
        else:
            os.remove(pickle_path)
    # Try to log in normally.
    data = helper.request_post(url, payload)
    # Handle case where mfa or challenge is required.
    if "mfa_required" in data:
        mfa_token = _ = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(
            None, "MFA code", "Please type in the MFA code: "
        )
        payload["mfa_code"] = mfa_token
        res = helper.request_post(url, payload, jsonify_data=False)
        while res.status_code != 200:
            mfa_token = _ = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(
                None,
                "MFA code",
                "That MFA code was not correct. Please type in another MFA code: ",
            )
            payload["mfa_code"] = mfa_token
            res = helper.request_post(url, payload, jsonify_data=False)
        data = res.json()
    elif "challenge" in data:
        challenge_id = data["challenge"]["id"]
        sms_code, _ = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(
            None, "Get Robinhood code", "Enter Robinhood code for validation: "
        )
        res = authentication.respond_to_challenge(challenge_id, sms_code)
        while "challenge" in res and res["challenge"]["remaining_attempts"] > 0:
            sms_code, _ = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(
                None,
                "Get Robinhood code",
                "That code was not correct. {0} tries remaining. Please type in another code: ".format(
                    res["challenge"]["remaining_attempts"]
                ),
            )
            res = authentication.respond_to_challenge(challenge_id, sms_code)
        helper.update_session("X-ROBINHOOD-CHALLENGE-RESPONSE-ID", challenge_id)
        data = helper.request_post(url, payload)
    # Update Session data with authorization or raise exception with the information present in data.
    if "access_token" in data:
        token = "{0} {1}".format(data["token_type"], data["access_token"])
        helper.update_session("Authorization", token)
        helper.set_login_state(True)
        data["detail"] = "logged in with brand new authentication code."
        if store_session:
            with open(pickle_path, "wb") as f:
                pickle.dump(
                    {
                        "token_type": data["token_type"],
                        "access_token": data["access_token"],
                        "refresh_token": data["refresh_token"],
                        "device_token": device_token,
                    },
                    f,
                )
    else:
        raise Exception(data["detail"])
    return data


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    login_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.username_le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.password_le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(echoMode=QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        login_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Login")
        login_btn.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        flay = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self)
        flay.addRow("Username:", self.username_le)
        flay.addRow("Password:", self.password_le)
        flay.addRow(login_btn)

    def on_clicked(self):
        username = self.username_le.text()
        password = self.password_le.text()
        try:
            data = login(username, password)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Although a more robust solution would be to implement the requests using Qt Network.